# Underscore.js, testing if entire array is in another array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

A little new to Underscore.js here.  I'm trying filter an array of objects by testing whether all items in a `tags` array are present in an object's `tags`.

So something like this, using Underscore's `filter` and `every` methods:

```
/* the set of data */
var colors = [
  {
    "id": "001",
    "tags": ["color_family_white", "tone_warm", "room_study"]
  }, 
  {
    "id": "002",
    "tags": ["color_family_white", "tone_neutral"]
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "tags": ["color_family_red", "tone_bright", "room_kitchen"]
  }
];

/* an example of white I might want to filter on */
var tags = ["color_family_white", "room_study"];

var results = _.filter(colors, function (color) {
    return _.every(tags, function() { /* ??? what to do here */} );
});
```

All tags should be present on `color.tags`.  So this should return only color 001.

This shows roughly what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/tsargent/EtuS7/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`indexOf`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) would work:

```
var results = _.filter(colors, function (color) {
    return _.every(tags, function(tag) { return _.indexOf(color.tags, tag) > -1; } );
});
```

Or the built-in [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function:

```
var results = _.filter(colors, function (color) {
    return _.every(tags, function(tag) { return color.tags.indexOf(tag) > -1; } );
});
```

But for brevity, you could also use the [`difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) function:

```
var results = _.filter(colors, function (color) {
    return _.difference(tags, color.tags).length === 0;
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/EtuS7/6/)